# Limit rotation of rigidbody?

Tags: physics, constraints, rigidbody

I've been working on a drumset and I'm facing some trouble with the cymbals as I want them to move dynamically if hit. I tried setting them up as active rigidbodies and the joists as passive rigidbodies in the hope that that would make it physically accurate. Unfortunately, the cymbal always clips through the joist as the collision detection is probably not accurate enough. Also, it's most practical if the joist is parent to the cymbal, so the passive rigidbody idea wouldn't work anyway. So I decided to fake my way around it; I locked the location so it doesn't fall down and I tried to use the "Limit rotation" constraint so it doesn't spin all the way around.

Two problems:

1. If the cymbal is hit by another rigidbody, the constraint doesn't take effect, it just spins all the way around.
2. If the rigidbody that hits it is set to "Animated" (which would be a necessity for the drumsticks) the rigidbody simulation doesn't work at all and it just passes through the cymbal without affecting it in any way.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should review some of the Rigid Body *Constraints* that are available -- may need an empty to relate the cymbal to joists.  e.g., https://youtu.be/YW_6WqFiAIw

Comment: Hello and welcome! For visitors as well as for people who could answer your question, it would always be helpful here if you additionally use images in your question to clarify what exactly you mean and where your problem lies. Thank you!